# How to eliminate transparent line on a rendered textured mesh with solidify

Tags: rendering, texturing, modifiers, blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view

I'd really appreciate if someone could help me with this, it's been driving me nuts.
I've been making a stylized hair mesh with solid a solid texture (purple-ish like the one below) and applied a solidify modifier with a node setup in order to simulate contour lines (I'd rather use this method vs Freestyle). It was all good but then I wanted to add a texture to the hair, like the red one below.

[image: Mesh with the texture]

But then when I tried to render the scene using BI, a transparent line appeared between the mesh and the solidify modifier (Note that the previous purple mesh doesn't have that)
[image: Transparent line]

Now, when i switch to rendered viewport this problem is not appearing

[image: Rendered Viewport]

So if anyone could help in any way it would be much appreciated!

I'll leave the blend file
[image]

Comment: The textures are not linked to your file. File->External Data->Automatically Pack into .blend

Comment: Oops, my bad. Updated File